# Cant connect remotely to SQL Server instance using name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL Server running multiple instances with their own IP address.

It goes like this

```
MyServer IP - 10.21.1.180

MyInstance1 IP-1 - 10.21.1.137
MyInstance1 IP-2 - Dynamic Port: 0

MyInstance2 IP-1 - 10.21.1.138
MyInstance2 IP-2 - Dynamic Port: 0
etc...
```

Now, I am able to connect to the instances using either it's IP or the server's IP with the assigned dynamic port. Remotely and Locally.

Here is the problem:

using the instance's name, (MyServer\MyInstance1), I can only connect locally but not remotely.

I have all firewalls turned off, but doesnt seem to help.
SQL Server Browser is also running

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to assign different *IP* addresses to the instances on *one* server, rather than just different ports? In order for that to work your server has to actually have multiple network cards or otherwise permit traffic on multiple IPs at the same time. SQL Server alone can't make that possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes. AWS allows you to have multiple IPs in 1 NIC. I already got that part to work, in fact.

Comment: Have you confirmed that **both** AWS Security Groups and Windows Firewall allow remote access to udp/1434 on the AWS server? Instance name resolution requires that the SQL Browser service is accessible on the target server. Clients use the SQL Server Resolution Protocol over udp/1434 to query the Browser service for the TCP port on which the instance name is listening, then establish a TCP connection on that port to execute queries.